# Javascript problem with iframe that's hidden before loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe, jscrollpane

I have a page that contains an `iframe` that gets loaded using Javascript:

**index.html**

```
<iframe id="myFrame" width="800" height="600" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<div id="loader"><!-- some loading indicator --></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunction() {
  var myFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
  var loader = document.getElementById('loader');

  loader.style.display = 'block';

  myFrame.src = 'myFrame.html';
  myFrame.onload = function() {
    myFrame.style.display = 'block';
    loader.style.display = 'none';
  };
}
</script>
```

The page that gets loaded in the `iframe` contains some Javascript logic which calculates the sizes of certain elements for the purposes of adding a JS driven scrollbar (jScrollPane + jQuery Dimensions).

**myFrame.html**

```
<div id="scrollingElement" style="overflow: auto;">
  <div id="several"></div>
  <div id="child"></div>
  <div id="elements"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function() {
  $('#scrollingElement').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

This works in Chrome (and probably other Webkit browsers), but fails in Firefox and IE because at the time `jScrollPane` gets called, all the elements are still invisble and jQuery Dimensions is unable to determine any element's dimensions.

Is there a way to make sure my `iframe` is visible *before* `$(document).ready(...)` gets called? Other than using `setTimeout` to delay `jScrollPane`, which is something I definitely want to avoid.

Comment: Why not just use the javascript from the page directly?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata this was over 5 years ago so I can't really remember, but I know there was a good reason for it :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some browsers assume that when "display:none" is applied to replaced elements (like Flash or an iframe) the visual info for that element is no longer needed. So, if the element is later displayed by the CSS, the browser will actually recreate the visual data form scratch.

I imagine that having the iframe default to "display:none;" makes the browser skip the rendering of the HTML so the tags don't have any dimensions. I would set the visibility to "hidden" or position it off the page rather than use "display:none;".

Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

instead of making the iframe invisible by using `display:none`, you could try to...

... set `visibility:hidden`

... set `position:absolute; top:-600px;`

... set `opacity:0`

or something else that makes jQuery "see" the objects but not the user (and reset the used css-attributes in your `myFrame.onload` function).

Comment: Also, z-index: -1

Answer (score -2):

`visibility:collapse;
display:hidden;
height:0px;`

Will work to get rid of white space too..
The iframe will also load..

Comment: display:hidden? I know "visibility:hidden", I don't see display:hidden in the documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score -5):

Hidden iframes are a huge security issue. Probably best to try to find another way to accomplish what you want, if it is legitimate, because hopefully future browsers will get rid of this feature altogether. http://blog.opendns.com/2012/07/10/opendns-security-team-blackhole-exploit/

Comment: Absolutely not helpful, first of all, how could "not using iframes" prevent bad guys from exploiting the security flaws of iframes anyway(?!?). And asking him to wait for the webdevelopers utopia to come, where all browsers support only the "real stuff" ain't helping either.