# jquery toggle cutting off iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, toggle

I'm trying to figure out a way to get an iframe to load with jquery toggle.  I can get the iframe to toggle, but the iframe is truncated each time and only about ~20% of the iframe is displayed.  The rest is cut-off.

http://jsfiddle.net/purpletenspeed/0dvdye07/2/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

HTML

```
<ul <li> <a href="#" class="show_hide"> Toggle </a>

<div class="slidingDiv">
    <iframe title="Launch Chat" width="500" height="600" src="https://home-c4.incontact.com/inContact/ChatClient/ChatClient.aspx?poc=8824e96a-2f91-4dbd-b9c0-eaf91a26bd48&bu=12" frameborder="0 </iframe>
</div>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").toggle();
});

});
```

css

```
.slidingDiv {
height: 600px;
width: 300;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
display:none
}
```

Comment: You have nested iframes. That's a recipe for a headache when it comes to sizing. It's the inner one that's cutting off.

Comment: UM, the problem is not with toggle, the issue is whatever is calculating the height inside that iframe.

Comment: Is their a better way then using an iframe?  I really just want to show/hide the chat window

Comment: One possible solution (you have to wait for iframe to be loaded) http://jsfiddle.net/0dvdye07/6/  See why you have this kind of issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/2786429/1414562

Comment: Sorry, this should be the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0dvdye07/7/

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for your response jsfiddle.net/0dvdye07/7 seems to be working well.  One thing i noticed is that the page jumps back to the top after clicking the toggle button and I have to scroll back down again.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JamesD You should prevent default behaviour on anchor click: http://jsfiddle.net/0dvdye07/8/

Answer (score 0):

well you have problem in your `.slidingDiv` css. make the width and height to match with your iframe:

```
.slidingDiv {
height: 600px;
width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
display:none
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dvdye07/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your response Ashkan!  I updated the CSS and it doesn't appear to change any behavior.

Comment: what about the fiddle?

Comment: The fiddle is working fine.  Must be an issue with my webpage.  Thanks again for your help!